# how to customize wordpress shortcode function to get every category post by shortcode Variable?

Tags: wordpress, function, categories, shortcode, posts

I'm using following code to create a WordPress shortcode [educationposts] to show posts of category named  "education".

How to set this shortcode function to be flexible as can show any category by changing shortcode like this [posts=education] or [posts=blog]

Thanks

```
/*** show post category ***/
function pwp_postsbycategory() {
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => 'education', 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) ); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $string .= '<ul class="postsbycategory widget_recent_entries">';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $string .= '<li>';
            $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 75, 75) ) . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
        } else { 
            // if no featured image is found
            $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
        }
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
$string .= '</ul>';

return $string;

/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
}
// Add a shortcode
add_shortcode('educationposts', 'pwp_postsbycategory');
/*** show post category ***/
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by set an $atts in function.

```
/*** show post category ***/
function pwp_postsbycategory($atts) {
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'category_name' => $atts['cat'], 'posts_per_page' => 5 ) ); 

if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    $string .= '<ul class="postsbycategory widget_recent_entries">';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
            $string .= '<li>';
            $string .= '<a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, array( 75, 75) ) . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
        } else { 
            // if no featured image is found
            $string .= '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() .'" rel="bookmark">' . get_the_title() .'</a></li>';
        }
    }
} else {
    // no posts found
}
$string .= '</ul>';

return $string;

/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
}
// Add a shortcode
add_shortcode('posts', 'pwp_postsbycategory');
/*** show post category ***/
```